# Certain web sites are blocked on all Azure Virtual Machines

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

If you have an azure virtual machine, login to it then open any browser and attempt to go to:
http://www.expedia.com

You will see the following message:

> Access Denied
>
> You don't have permission to access "http://www.expedia.com" on this
>   server.
>
> Reference #18.27081160.1436970336.c0a3dfe

You can have a new virtual machine instance, with no browser cache or cookies what-so-ever and you will see the access denied error on expedia and several other sites.  It is not a browser specific issue.

Any clue on how to get around this?

Comment: never experienced such issue (from West- and Norht-Europe)! And I use Azure VM on a daily basis. What Data Centre are you using? Also, do you turn off the IE enhanced Security setting ?

Comment: Which OS is the virtual machine running?

Comment: Interesting issue, but it doesn't belong on StackOverflow (it's not a programming question). Perhaps post to ServerFault?

Answer (score 0):

This is not relevant question for this site but for your information.
I hope because site is not running on original URL basically this site redirecting on .com to co.in that is why azure is restricting.

behavior of your link is given here.

www.expedia.co.in/?rfrr=Redirect.From.www.expedia.com%2F